# find the postion of first occurance of the below given tag in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm using a the below given step to find the position of `<heading` tag which is occurring more than once. But I need the position of the **first occurrence** only.

I'm doing this shell script in Windows using cygwin tool

```
transformationTag=`grep -nE "<heading " "$xmlFile"|cut -d ":" -f1`
```

this will give an output like: `17 24 46`

From this, how can I retrieve `17` only?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pipe it through `head`:

```
transformationTag=`grep -nE "<heading " "$xmlFile"|cut -d ":" -f1 | head -1 `
```